Does ObjectReef supports Data Transfer Objects (DTO)?
I'm wondering how to create something like a Data Transfer Object in ObjectReef.
When I call an operation from the API I can use parameters that are either simple types or references to existing objects.
context App::foo(s: string, n: integer, d: date)
post:
   -- some stuff here

Is there a method for a more concise way of passing arguments to operation via API?

You can use a JsonObject object as a DTO and just read its properties like of any other object.
context App::foo(argsDTO: JsonObject)
post:
    self.Name = argsDTO.name
    self.Age = argsDTO.age

and from client application like ie. js app just pass a Json as argument
await fetch('http://localhost:1996/json/v001/app/foo',
        {
            method:'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'Accept':'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    argsDTO:{
                        name: 'Alice',
                        age: 24
                    }
                })
        });

